# Hide Disqus on password-protected posts until password is entered?

Tags: wordpress, password-protection, disqus

I need to hide Disqus comments on password-protected posts until users enter the correct password. I've already contacted Disqus about this... first they told me to enable the disqus_developer variable. So I added this to header.php in Wordpress:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var disqus_developer = 1; // developer mode is on
</script>
```

But that didn't do anything. Then Disqus support told me:

> You would have to add some logic to your code that doesn’t load Disqus
>   unless the password is entered. This is something you would need to
>   customize in your theme/template.

They gave no direction on how to accomplish this. What do I need to do?

Comment: Just to add, `disqus_developer` is [no longer a supported configuration variable](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables). See http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1053796-best-practices-for-staging-development-and-preview-sites for alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edit plugins/disqus-comment-system/comments.php and add the following code somewhere at the beginning of that file:

```
<?php if ( post_password_required() ) { ?>
<p class="nocomments">Whatever text you want.</p>
        <?php
                return;
         } ?>
```

Comment: You are the best thing on the internet. THANK YOU.